# Problema construyendo datos de un DataSet manualmente C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagrid, visual-studio-2010, dataset

Tengo un `dataset` que contiene una estructura de 12 columnas y de forma manual  le agrego 3 columnas `Entrada Parámetro` , `Salida Parámetro` y `Parámetro` a partir de otro `dataset` , para luego vincularlo a un `DataGridView`, estoy trabajando con rango de fechas para cargar los datos, pero se me ha presentado un caso que no se como resolver. Ya tengo mi dataset con las columnas deseadas agregadas, solo basta con insertar los datos en las filas correspondientes, antes que nada detallare la información relevante para la pregunta. el problema es el siguiente: .

> 1 - `dataset_manual` es al que le agrego las 3 columnas adicionales manualmente. **(Puede o no tener datos)**
>
> 2 - `dataset_datos` siempre tendrá datos cargados de una consulta.

**Con los datos pueden ocurrir varios casos:**

1- Si el `dataset_manual` no tiene datos,  lo llenaré solo con los datos del `dataset_datos` (Esto esta resuelto).

2- Si el `dataset_manual` tiene la misma cantidad de datos que el `dataset_datos` llenar todas las columnas en su fila correspondiente. (Esto esta resuelto)

3- Si el `dataset_manual` tiene menos datos que el `dataset_datos` y el valor de las filas corresponden en ambos dataset con el mismo valor de fecha y la posicion del valor esta en el mismo indice, llenar el `dataset_manual` con las filas correspondientes y las 3 columnas adicionales llenarlas con el `dataset_datos` (Esto esta resuelto)

4- si el `dataset_manual` tiene menos datos que el `dataset_datos` y el valor de las filas **NO** corresponde en ambos dataset con el mismo valor de fecha y la posicion del valor no esta en el mismo indice. **(ESTE ES EL PROBLEMA)**.

Presento un ejemplo para poder entender de forma mas clara, suponga los datos siguiente para cada dataset:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente tengo este método que me funciona para los casos: 1, 2, 3:

```
int cantidad = dataset_manual.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

for (int indice = 0; indice < dataset_datos.Tables[0].Rows.Count; indice++)
{
    if (indice < cantidad_validacion)
    {
        //Actualizo las celdas
        dataset_manual.Tables[0].Rows[indice]["entrada_parametro"] = dataset_datos.Tables[0].Rows[indice]["entrada_parametro"];
        dataset_manual.Tables[0].Rows[indice]["salida_parametro"] = dataset_datos.Tables[0].Rows[indice]["salida_parametro"];
        dataset_manual.Tables[0].Rows[indice]["parametro"] = dataset_datos.Tables[0].Rows[indice]["parametro"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        //Creo las filas
         var fila = dataset_manual.Tables[0].NewRow();
         fila["entrada_parametro"] = dataset_datos.Tables[0].Rows[indice]["entrada_parametro"];
         fila["salida_parametro"] = dataset_datos.Tables[0].Rows[indice]["salida_parametro"];
         fila["parametro"] = dataset_datos.Tables[0].Rows[indice]["parametro"].ToString();
         dataset_manual.Tables[0].Rows.Add(fila);
     }
}
```

De este modo obtengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> La hora de Entrada/Salida : `01:00:00 p.m.` y `07:00:00 p.m.` corresponden al dia/fecha : `16/09/2017` y NO al dia 12.

**El Resultado que deseo Obtener es el siguiente:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para lograr esto he pensando en utilizar dos ciclos para recorrer ambos y preguntar si la fecha es igual, pero me irá alterando el dataset_manual y me distorsiona los datos:

```
                for (int indice = 0; indice < dataset_datos.Tables[0].Rows.Count; indice++)
                {
                    for (int indice2 = 0; indice2 < dataset_manual.Tables[0].Rows.Count; indice2++)
                    {
                        DateTime fecha_dsmanual = new DateTime();
                        DateTime fecha_dsdatos = new DateTime();

                        fecha_dsmanual = Convert.ToDateTime(dataset_manual.Tables[0].Rows[indice2]["fecha"].ToString());

                        fecha_dsdatos = Convert.ToDateTime(dataset_datos.Tables[0].Rows[indice]["fecha"].ToString());

                        if (fecha_dsmanual.ToShortDateString().Equals(fecha_dsdatos.ToShortDateString()))
                        {
                            //Actualizo las celdas
                            dataset_manual.Tables[0].Rows[indice2]["entrada_parametro"] = dataset_datos.Tables[0].Rows[indice]["entrada_parametro"];
                            dataset_manual.Tables[0].Rows[indice2]["salida_parametro"] = dataset_datos.Tables[0].Rows[indice]["salida_parametro"];
                            dataset_manual.Tables[0].Rows[indice2]["parametro"] = dataset_datos.Tables[0].Rows[indice]["parametro"].ToString();

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Creo las filas
                            var fila = dataset_manual.Tables[0].NewRow();
                            fila["entrada_parametro"] = dataset_datos.Tables[0].Rows[indice]["entrada_parametro"];
                            fila["salida_parametro"] = dataset_datos.Tables[0].Rows[indice]["salida_parametro"];
                            fila["parametro"] = dataset_datos.Tables[0].Rows[indice]["parametro"].ToString();
                            dataset_manual.Tables[0].Rows.Add(fila);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **Pueden sugerirme una idea?**

**Entorno:**  Visual Studio 2010 (WindowsForms C#) & .NET NetFramework 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que tienes un problema de base, y es que actualizas las filas basándote en su indice, en lugar de buscar cual es exactamente la fila que debes actualizar. Lo que yo haría sería usar LINQ para buscar la fila, y actualizarla si existe y si no crear una nueva. Algo asi:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x=>x.Field<DateTime>("Fecha")).ToList())
{
    var fila=dataset_manual.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(x=> x.Field<DateTime>("fecha").Date == ((DateTime)dr["fecha"]).Date).FirstOrDefault();

    if (fila!=null)
    {
         //Actualizar datos
         fila["entrada_parametro"]=(DateTime)dr["entrada_parametro"];
         fila["salida_parametro"]=(DateTime)dr["salida_parametro"];
         fila["parametro"]=dr["parametro"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
         //Añadir fila
         var fila2 = dataset_manual.Tables[0].NewRow();
         fila2["entrada_parametro"] = dr["entrada_parametro"];
         fila2["salida_parametro"] = dr["salida_parametro"];
         fila2["parametro"] = dr["parametro"].ToString();
         dataset_manual.Tables[0].Rows.Add(fila2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Efectivamente funciona, pero me muesta los datos [de esta forma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TrNH.png) voy a usar `dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[1], ListSortDirection.Ascending);` para ordernar los datos por fecha, para mostrarlo correctamente, **¿ O puede hacer el sort directamente con Linq?**

Comment: @J.Rodríguez puedes intentar ordenarlo en el foreach, o como bien dices en el datagridview directamente. Prueba el codigo que he editado a ver si asi te lo saca ordenado

Comment: No lo saca ordenado desde el `foreach`, pero ya lo ordenaré directamente en el `DataGridView`. Lo demás ya es historia, muchas gracias llevaba dos días codificando esta parte sin resultados, gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Se me presentó un inconveniente por no tener los datos ordenados dentro del dataset, como puedo ordenarlo por fecha? anteriormente lo ordené en el `DataGridView` asi: `dgrid.Sort(dgrid.Columns[1], ListSortDirection.Ascending);` Lo muestra en pantalla bien, pero cuando recorro el `Dataset` los valores no tienen las mismas posiciones, necesito ordenarlos directamente en el `Dataset` y no en el `DataGridView` recordandote que para ordenarlo solo tome en cuenta la fecha sin la hora.

Comment: Por alguna razón el `Oderby` del ciclo `foreach` `foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().OrderBy...` no está funcionando, por favor Ayudame.